# Is this the correct way to serve web page from S3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an Node server ( Ubuntu on  EC2  server ) which serves the data from the database. To serve html pages I am using S3 bucket. I am using the following in my code -

```
https.get(
           'https://s3_Url_Of_Page', 
           function(proxyRes) {
                       proxyRes.pipe(res);
           }
);
```

I am still not sure whether this causes the client to get the page directly from S3, or first the page is downloaded to my EC2 server then it is given to the client, if so how can I make the client get the page directly from S3 when client hits my server url without this intermediate downloading.

Comment: You are downloading the page to the EC2 server (that's what `http.get()` does) and streaming the response to the client (that's what `proxyRes.pipe(res)` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By piping the response the traffic goes through your EC2 server. You should send a redirect response to your client with the Location pointing to your S3 content. Then the browser will fetch the content directly from the bucket.

You need to enable public access for the S3 bucket.

Example:

```
 var http = require('http');
 var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     // http status 302 = temporary redirect; 301 = permanent redirect
     res.writeHead(302, {
         'Location': 'your/s3/bucket/path'
     });
     response.end();
 });
```

Comment: won't the url change because of that. Could you provide code to make it work.

Comment: Yes, the URL in the browser would then become the URL to your S3 bucket. I will give an example in my answer.

Comment: But Sir, I have my website url as https://mywebsite.com and when client goes on this site I need to send the login.html page to the client but the url should be https://mywebsite.com. This login.html file is on S3 so that later I can use cloud front to make loading faster.

Comment: I see. If you want to use cloudfront you should have a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html for description and examples. Solution would include DNS config and not be implemented in your code.